# C Backtracking, array permutations

Tags: c

I have some problems understanding backtraking. I need to count how many possible permutations can be generated using an array and to keep in mind some constraints.
My array represents a set of LED lights, each and one of them has a colour, a name and an intensity.
There can't be two lights of the same color next to each other and the difference of intensity between two adjacent leds shouldn't be greater than 'K'. 
I wrote the code, but something seems off. It counts too many permutations because some lights are repeating, even with the restrictions I implemented.

```
int verification ( led*  sol , int  a  , int  b )
{
    if( sol[a].intensity > sol[b].intensity ) 
        return  sol[ a ].intensity - sol[ b ].intensity;
    else 
        return  sol[ b ].intensity - sol[ a ].intensity;
}
int is_valid( led*  sol , int  n , int  level , int  K )
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0 ; i < level-1 ; i++ )
    {
        if( strcmp( sol[ i ].color, sol[ i+1].color ) ==0 || verification(sol , i , i+1) > K )
            return 0;
                if( strcmp( sol[ i ].name , sol[ i+1 ].name ) ==0 )
                        return 0;
            }
    return 1;
}
int is_solultion ( led*  sol , int  n , int  level , int  K )
{
        int i;
    if( n == level &&  is_valid ( sol , n , level , K ) )
                    return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
int  backtracking ( led*  sol , int  n , led*  l , int  level , int  K )
{
    int  i;
    int  sum =0;
    if( n == level &&  ! (is_solution ( sol , n , level , K ) ) ) 
        return 0;
    if( is_solution ( sol , n , level , K ) )
        return 1;
    for( i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ )
    {
        sol[ level ] = l [ i ] ;
        if ( este_valid ( sol , n , level+1, K ) )
            sum + = backtracking ( sol , n , l , nivel+1 , K );
    }  return sum;
}
```

Comment: Code - this is how the code looks like

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy and paste the code as text. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Comment: Also, please clarify: _the difference of intensity between them shouldn't be greater than 'K'_ It that between two adjacent leds or any two leds?

Comment: Why do you need backtracking for a problem such as this?  It seems reasonable to me to generate *all* permutations, testing each for validity with respect to your constraints.  That doesn't require backtracking.

Comment: *the difference between 2 adjacent leds*                                           Our teacher said we should use backtracking to eliminate the "unfavorable" cases that don't match the restrictions in advance.

Comment: My suggestion: first get your permutation code working, without any attempt to verify. Once you are confident that you can generate all permutations exactly once, then move on to the next part. (And here's a hint: when you generate a permutation, you can't use an element you've already used.)